# AS3: Draw a line along the common tangents of two circles

Tags: actionscript-3, math, geometry

**What I've got**
is two circles on the stage, circ1 and circ2. circ1 has radius 60, and circ2 has radius 30.

circ2 can be dragged around the stage in playback.

**What I want**
is two lines connecting the circles by their common outer tangents. This is working towards turning an old poster into an interactive funbox. Here's a [link to the poster](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_COwnPIDsWS4/R9YLLPtJ8iI/AAAAAAAAAJI/xYiWvOPP9Nk/s1600/hermann+eidenbenz+-+poter+for+%27werkbund+idea+and+werkbund+work.gif), it might help you understand what I mean (although for now I'm just going to worry about two circles on their own).

**The problem:**
I understand how to find common tangents with a pen and paper, but as soon as I try to conceive of how to put this into terms Flash might understand, my brain goes into meltdown. I have no idea how to make this happen using ActionScript.

**What I have tried:**
I've looked around, and [this is the closest thing I can find](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Tangents_between_two_circles) to what I'm trying to achieve (example app is downloadable at the bottom of the page). The only difference is that this includes interior tangents, which I don't need.

Unfortunately this source is written in Java, which, despite my best efforts, I don't understand enough to port to AS3.

So far all I have managed to achieve on my own is to define Points for the center of each circle, and then realize that I can't make flash solve equations for a variable. I then spent several hours Googling trying to figure out how to proceed from here.

Any help would be much appreciated, this is work for a school project that is due in the end of this week. I may have bitten off more than I can chew here, but it's too late to turn back now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not that hard to figure out by hand, but if you're determined to convert the Java code, at least post as much as you have right now and where you are stuck.

Comment: There may be 4 different lines that can connect your circles in the way you describe -- 2 on either side (as in the poster), and 2 from one side of the first circle to the *other* side of the other circle. Do you want to know them *all*, or just the non-crossing ones?

Comment: Here you have an interactive diagram, that can easily be converted to code: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/TangentTwoCirclesI.shtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's working code that does what you describe for two circles - assuming the two circles are the same size.  Otherwise it is an approximation, since it assumes the tangent points will be on a line perpendicular to that connecting the circle centers.

```
var point1 : Point = new Point(100, 100);
var point2 : Point = new Point(300, 50);
var radius1 : int = 60;
var radius2 : int = 30;

// if you draw a line from the first circle origo to
// the second origo, this is the angle of that line
var ang : Number = Math.atan2(point2.y - point1.y, point2.x - point1.x);

// find the first point on the circumference that is orthogonal
// to the line intersecting the two circle origos
var start1 : Point = new Point(point1.x + Math.cos(ang + Math.PI / 2) * radius1, 
                               point1.y + Math.sin(ang + Math.PI/2)* radius1);
var end1 : Point = new Point(point2.x + Math.cos(ang + Math.PI / 2) * radius2, 
                             point2.y + Math.sin(ang + Math.PI/2)* radius2);

// find the second point on the circumference that is orthogonal
// to the line intersecting the two circle origos
var start2 : Point = new Point(point1.x + Math.cos(ang - Math.PI / 2) * radius1, 
                               point1.y + Math.sin(ang - Math.PI/2)* radius1);
var end2 : Point = new Point(point2.x + Math.cos(ang - Math.PI / 2) * radius2,
                             point2.y + Math.sin(ang - Math.PI/2)* radius2);

// draw everything on the stage
this.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x0);
this.graphics.drawCircle(point1.x, point1.y, radius1);
this.graphics.drawCircle(point2.x, point2.y, radius2);

this.graphics.moveTo(start1.x, start1.y);
this.graphics.lineTo(end1.x, end1.y);

this.graphics.moveTo(start2.x, start2.y);
this.graphics.lineTo(end2.x, end2.y);
```

Comment: this works perfectly, only thing i could ask for is for it to be in a function, but that was easy for me to take care of. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
function DrawTangents(p1 : Point, r1 : Number, p2 : Point, r2 : Number) : void {
    var dx = p2.x - p1.x;
    var dy = p2.y - p1.y;
    var dist = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

    this.graphics.drawCircle(p1.x, p1.y, r1);
    this.graphics.drawCircle(p2.x, p2.y, r2);

    if (dist <= Math.abs(r2 - r1)) {
        // The circles are coinciding. There are no valid tangents.
        return;
    }

    // Rotation from the x-axis.
    var angle1 = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

    // Relative angle of the normals. This is equal for both circles.
    var angle2 = Math.acos((r1 - r2)/dist);

    this.graphics.moveTo(p1.x + r1 * Math.cos(angle1 + angle2),
                         p1.y + r1 * Math.sin(angle1 + angle2));
    this.graphics.lineTo(p2.x + r2 * Math.cos(angle1 + angle2),
                         p2.y + r2 * Math.sin(angle1 + angle2));

    this.graphics.moveTo(p1.x + r1 * Math.cos(angle1 - angle2),
                         p1.y + r1 * Math.sin(angle1 - angle2));
    this.graphics.lineTo(p2.x + r2 * Math.cos(angle1 - angle2),
                         p2.y + r2 * Math.sin(angle1 - angle2));
}
```

Comment: thank you also, i used some bits of your code (eg coinciding circles detection) in my end product.